# How to do this scroll effect which automatically adjusts to your viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

http://teacakedesign.com/

This is the website I am referring to. It will auto adjust the the size of the scrolled items to fit the available space in your browser's viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best solution but this is how I would start:
set the height of the container to the number of elements * 100 % (example: 5 elements -> 500%). Each inner element is 100 / n elements tall.
In the js file I would check the height of the window when the user scrolls and then animate the scrollbar up or down "n" pixels.